# Redirect sys.stdout to Matlab terminal

Tags: python, matlab

A custom python function, written by me, takes about a couple of hours to complete one run. I had provided print-outputs at all significant steps not only for better debugging but also for allowing the end-user to see what the program is doing at any moment and (mentally) estimate the remaining time which is more satisfying than staring at a black screen for hours.

This worked fine until I had to call the function from within Matlab. Matlab flushes sys.stdout at one go, after the entire command is executed. So, I see nothing but "Busy" in Matlab alongside a blank Matlab terminal for a good few hours followed by a sudden dump of hundreds of lines.

**So**, how to redirect sys.stdout to Matlab terminal? Any equivalent method that will allow me to consult the print-ouputs ON THE GO are welcome. Or, maybe, there's no way out except redirecting sys.stdout to a .txt file and Tail-ing it (manually) to see progress?

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: Also, how do you call the Python function? Are you using the MATLAB-Python bridge, or calling through the shell?

Comment: Windows 11. MATLAB-Python bridge.